# 403 error when trying to pass a specific series of characters

Tags: php, mysql

I can submit information through an html form and insert it into a mysql DB without any problems. However, if what I've typed in has a word that is in quotations followed by a hyphen and then a value - even with spaces - (ex: "name"-place), I get a 403 error after submission. I've tried addslashes, I've tried mysql_escape_string, I've tried htmlspecialchars() and nothing seems to work. When I remove one of the two quotations, it works just fine. I've read through lots of posts and have tried several suggestions with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: If you're using `mysql_query` that's a huge problem, but it can be fixed. Can you edit your question to include the code you're working on?

Comment: You are correct - I am using mysql_query. Should I move to mysqli_query?

Comment: You should switch to either mysqli or PDO.  See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Perfect - I read the link - I will do just that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, I tried but no luck. submitted the value (from input form on previous page) "test"-6 and received the error. However, I tried "test"-t and no issues - so, when there is a quote (") plus (-) plus a number, it errors, but a quote (") plus (-) and letter equals no error - weird...